# Multiple Add-Ins using one C# Pipeline

Tags: c#, mef, add-in, pipeline, maf

Is it possible to have one add-in pipeline (MEF) but depending on the add-in class type perform different functionality?

Example: if I have add-ins for reporting (with each add-in performing a specialized reporting function) and add-ins for Calculation (with each add-in performing different calculations for a different part of the application), is there a way to set this up in one pipeline? Or do i have to setup an individual pipeline for each function that I want add-ins supported for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should really look at the MEF documentation and yes you can have multiple add-in with one pipeline(composition). look for examples with the MEF [ImportMany] attribute.

Comment: thanks for your tip. the MEF [ImportMany] tutorial I found (http://zamjad.wordpress.com/2011/05/11/using-directorycatalog-with-importmany-attribute-in-mef/) is a lot simpler than the Add-In Pipeline I was using